# Define a Fn alias type that accept a vector of generics

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a type alias for a function that accepts a Vec of T as a parameter and I want to specify bounds for the generic type so that each instance of the function accept a vector of the same type, not a dynamic one.

This is my code:

```
trait MyTrait {}

struct Foo {}
impl MyTrait for Foo {}

struct Bar {}
impl MyTrait for Bar {}

type MyFn = Box<dyn Fn(Vec<T: MyTrait>)>;
```

I get

> wrong number type of type arguments: expected at least 1 but found 0

I would like to end up with instances of `MyFn` that accept a vector of only `Foo` or only `Bar`, not both

Comment: `type MyFn<T: MyTrait> = Box<dyn Fn(Vec<T>)>;`?

Comment: @Jmb it compiles but it says `the bound will not be checked when the type alias is used, and should be removed`

Comment: Anyway I could use a generic Fn without restricting its bounds

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jmb I figured out that I have to declare the type using a generic without bounds, then I can add bounds directly in the struct using the alias type:

```
trait MyTrait {}

struct Foo {}
impl MyTrait for Foo {}

struct Bar {}
impl MyTrait for Bar {}

type MyFn<T> = Box<dyn Fn(Vec<T>)>;

struct MyStr<T: MyTrait> {
    value: MyFn<T>
}
```